# Is there a general rule for a phrase like "I am not a big movie person"?

Tags: grammar, etymology, phrases, expressions

I've been trying to find a general rule for these sorts of expressions:

- I've never been a big movie person.
- He's never been a big New Year’s resolution person.

I can't find any dictionary or grammar resources that talk about it, yet it's not exactly uncommon in English language to use this sort of phrase.

My guess is that it's a variation on "a big movie fan". Am I on the right track, or is there a better explanation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. There are two separate issues: (1) the meaning of *big* here and (2) the attributive use of a noun to modify a word for a person in a specific role.

**big** (adj.)

> Filled with or characterized by enthusiasm and interest
>
> *I'm a big fan of soy foods but urge you to choose them wisely.* — Andrew Weil
>
> Active and enthusiastic
>
> *My mother is a big baker, and so was my grandmother …* — Melissa Parks
>
> *I'm not a big shopper, so for me to actually like a store is really saying something.* — Matt Cameron [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/big)

Nouns are frequently used attributively as modifiers of other nouns in many different ways. A *movie goer* is a person who goes to many movies. A *Cubs fan* is a fan *of* the Cubs. A *shoe store* is, of course, one that *sells* shoes. A *travel agent* helps you *plan and book* your trips. A *book person* is a person who *reads/likes* books. A *pie person* could be someone who enjoys *eating* pies, *making* pies, or both.

*We readers have to grasp the implicit logical connection between the nouns—a connection that isn't always apparent.* For example, a *stone lion* is a statue of a lion made of stone. A *toy lion* is a toy in the shape of a lion. A *toy poodle* may be a child's toy or a pet (a toy breed). A *paper tiger* is an expression for someone who appears threatening, but actually isn't. A *paper doll* is made of paper, but a *paper boy* is a boy who delivers newspapers on a *paper route*. Some constructions (open compounds) have a specific meaning and can be difficult to figure out: a *shoe tree* is a form placed in shoes that are not being worn to help keep their shape. Context may help you in these cases; a dictionary can clear things up.

So a *a [big] [New Year’s resolution] person* is a person who enjoys making New Year's resolutions. When someone says "I am *not* a big [X] person," it can be a polite way of saying they don't care for [X] very much or even at all, especially after someone has just said [X] is one of their favorite things

We can now understand constructions like:

> "My mother likes to cook, but she isn't a *big bread baker / big pie
> person / big cookie maker*."
>
> "I'm not a big mystery reader/fan/buff/person."
>
> I'm a people person.

Comment: How can someone enjoy and not enjoy? "So a a [big] [New Year’s resolution] person is a person who **enjoys** making New Year's resolutions. The take-away is that they probably **don't** enjoy it." Are you missing a negation, or, in the 2nd sentence, referring to the OP's original quote? Confuses me.

Comment: @NigelTouch That's because I left out the negation! Sorry--corrected.

Answer (score 0):

What you have with, for example, *a big movie person* is *big* meaning *active and enthusiastic* and *movie person* meaning *liker of movies*. You can put just about any noun in front of *person* and it means *liker of noun*. So:

> *I am an active and enthusiastic liker of movies.*

If you leave out *big* you get:

> *I am a liker of movies.*

If you add *not* to that you get:

> *I am not a liker of movies.*

If you add back *big* you get:

> *I am not an active and enthusiastic liker of movies.*

I think you can see that, when using *not*, the addition of *big* softens the statement — allowing that you might like movies, just not all that much. Without *big*, you like movies little if at all.

Usage notes:

> **big** *adjective*
> **2a :** active and enthusiastic
>           <sub>// My mother is a big baker, and so was my grandmother... *— Melissa
> Parks*
>           // I’m not a big shopper, so
> for me to actually like a store is really saying something. *— Matt
> Cameron*</sub>
>
> **person** *noun*
> **2 :** a person who likes or enjoys something specified
>           <sub>// Our new friends are real party people.
> [=our new friends like parties]
>           //
> I’m just not a city person. [=I do not like the city very much]
>
>         // She’s always been a cat person. [=she
> likes cats a lot]</sub>
>
> <sub>Source:
> [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/)</sub>

Seen about:

> I’m not a big seafood person but was willing to give Joe’s Crab Shack
> a try.
>  <sub>BLOG: *Times Union* — Snapshot: ★½ for Joe’s Crab
> Shack</sub>
>
> I mean, this ride, I’m not a big roller-coaster person, but the
> technology that they’ve used was so amazing...
>  <sub>SPOK: *NBC* —
> Today Show</sub>
>
> You’re a big Twitter person, too. Text me up.
>  <sub>SPOK: *CBS* —
> This Morning</sub>
>
> More examples at [Corpus of Contemporary American
> English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=103713403).

Answer (score -1):

It's in the dictionary under "[person](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/person)":

> [with modifier] An individual characterized by a preference or liking for a specified thing.
>
> > ‘she's not a cat person’

Though the phrase collocates with "big", it's not exclusively used with it.

I'm not sure that it's linked to "fan" other than being a synonym. The words aren't interchangeable: It sounds very awkward to say "people fan", for example.

Here's Dictionary.com for the [origin of people person](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/people-person#):

> The first records of the phrase *people person* come from around 1966. It is used similarly to terms like cat person (someone who likes cats) or morning person (someone who likes mornings), which refer to someone who enjoys a particular thing. In this case, a people person is a person who likes other people.